Select a range between the active cell and a particular column
I want to write a VBA script that selects the cells between the active cell and column i in my excel spreadsheet.
For instance, if I am on cell A1, activating this script selects the cells from A1 to I1, or if I am on cell D3, selects the cells from D3 to I3.
Your input will be greatly appreciated.
I have tried this code:
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:I1").Select
End Sub


But if I start from say B1, it will select cells from B1 to J1 instead of I1.

Try the following sub.
Sub test()
    Range(ActiveCell.Address, "I" & ActiveCell.Row()).Select
End Sub


Nit picking here, but to make it less scary (an unqualified Range defined by two strings) and shorter, you could use the object as the first argument i.e. ActiveCell instead of ActiveCell.Address. What is the purpose of the set of parentheses (()) after ActiveCell.Row?

Sub Test()
  ActiveCell.Resize(10, 1).Select
End Sub

ActiveCell is a Range object .Resize method changes its size to 10 rows by 1 column, and then .Select

It would be ActiveCell.Resize(1, 10).Select to select row wise cells.

From Column to Column
Basic (Select Active Cell to Column I)
Keep in Mind

Application.Goto will activate the correct worksheet and select the range no matter which sheet is active.
.Select will raise an error if the cell is not on the active sheet.
Of course, it doesn't matter in this particular case because you're dealing with the active cell.

Sub SelectActiveCellToColumnIBasic()
    With ActiveCell
        Application.Goto .Worksheet.Range(.Cells, .EntireRow.Columns("I"))
    End With
End Sub


If you write the code like this, you can safely replace ActiveCell with any other referenced cell.

Dynamic (Select Column to Column)

Here you could use a range or a selection instead of ActiveCell to select multiple rows.
Note that only the left-most column (arg.Column) of each area of the range is considered.

The Calling Procedures (Usage)
ActiveCell
Sub SelectActiveCellToColumnI()
    SelectColumnToColumn ActiveCell, "I"
End Sub

Selection
Sub SelectSelectionToColumnI()
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub
    SelectColumnToColumn Selection, "I"
End Sub

The Helper Method
Sub SelectColumnToColumn( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal EdgeColumnID As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal IgnoreRangeToTheRightOfEdge As Boolean = False)
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Worksheet
    
    Dim eColumn As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        eColumn = ws.Columns(EdgeColumnID).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
    If eColumn = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim urg As Range, rrg As Range, arg As Range, ColumnOffset As Long
    Dim AreRowsInvalid As Boolean, IsAnyRowFound As Boolean
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        ColumnOffset = eColumn - arg.Column
        AreRowsInvalid = False
        If IgnoreRangeToTheRightOfEdge Then
            If ColumnOffset < 0 Then
                AreRowsInvalid = True
            End If
        End If
        If Not AreRowsInvalid Then
            With arg.Columns(1)
                Set rrg = ws.Range(.Cells, .Offset(, ColumnOffset))
            End With
            If IsAnyRowFound Then
                Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
            Else
                Set urg = rrg
                IsAnyRowFound = True ' never reset
            End If
        End If
    Next arg
    
    If Not IsAnyRowFound Then Exit Sub
        
    'Debug.Print rg.Address & vbLf & urg.Address
    Application.Goto urg
    
End Sub

